# jdbcTemplate, stored procedure returning value

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I have a stored procedure that accepts parameters and returns a long value.

How can I use jdbcTemplate to call this stored procedure and get the returned value.

```
String sql = ""call my_proc(?,?)"
long ret = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Long.class, param1,param2);
```

Is this right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **SimpleJdbcCall** to invoke stored procedure.
Below is the code snippet which illustrates invocation of stored procedure and takes return value,

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall =  new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplateSP).withProcedureName("spGetEmpDetails");
Map<String, Object> inParamMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
inParamMap.put("EmpID", String.valueOf(id));
SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource(inParamMap);


Map<String, Object> simpleJdbcCallResult = jdbcCall.execute(in);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to call stored procedures in Spring.
You can use **SimpleJdbcTemplate** and you have option to use **JdbcTemplate** as well. It seems you are interested to use JdbcTemplate.

Below are available approaches to call a Stored procedure using JdbcTemplate

1. Using **CallableStatementCreator** based approach
2. Extended abstract class **StoredProcedure**
3. Using **CallableStatement**

Plenty of examples are available in internet for each approach. Chose wisely any of them.

By the way, your code seems ok. But for complex stored procedure call calling stored procedure like this `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject` is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it looks right.
syntax depends on database, e.g. for postgres it will be:

```
Long ret = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select my_proc(?,?)", Long.class, param1, param2);
```

queryForObject throws exception if result is empty, hope you will handle that